# Why can't the system import modules from the Python Standard Library in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, python, import

Boy have I had a long day today. Like most Linux days it started out fun but then turned funny.

The whole day was more or less spent reinstalling a basic Gnome Ubuntu system. Everything went swimmingly until I started with the XBMC part of the installation. After wrestling with PPAs and apt-get for hours I finally got it installed, but then it all turned awkward in a hurry.

It simply refused to start up. I clicked the icon and nothing happened for a good few seconds. The screen then flickered black for an instant, but after that nothing. I started from a terminal and it showed an error message saying it couldn't import Python's os and shutil modules. I found that mighty strange since both modules are part of the Python Standard Library.

Finally, in a bizarre twist, it turns out this doesn't seem to be a XBMC problem, suddenly apt-get started complaining too.

TL,DR: I (nor the system) can't import any Standard Library modules in Python in Ubuntu! Help!

Is this a path problem? Or have I actually managed to uninstall some vital python packages, if so which ones?

I am running Ubuntu 10.10 if that is of importance.

EDIT: I think I figured out what was wrong. I had accidentally split one line into two in fstab. The line in question was the root directory, so my guess is that the faulty mount (it was split right at the flags part) caused the system to create bad blocks here and there. Through some hard and bitter fire fighting I managed to fix the python problem (I simply copied over bits and pieces from /usr/lib from a working 10.10 system to the bad one, and python suddenly sprung to life again). But I couldn't figure out the initial error I had, a seg fault when starting xbmc. Then today I just happened to randomly open the fstab file, where I corrected the split line, and after that xbmc was working again. Phew. I will go sleep now.

Here are some dumps to show the error messages: (I forgot to copy the XBMC error message, but it looked exactly the same as these below, i.e., it couldn't import the os module)

First from apt-get:

```
tv@tv:/usr/lib$ sudo apt-get autoremove
[sudo] password for tv: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libqt3-mt python-qt3 python-sip
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 19.2MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 75111 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python-qt3 ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/update-python-modules", line 11, in <module>
    import sys,os,shutil
ImportError: No module named os
dpkg: error processing python-qt3 (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/update-python-modules", line 11, in <module>
    import sys,os,shutil
ImportError: No module named os
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Removing python-sip ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/update-python-modules", line 11, in <module>
    import sys,os,shutil
ImportError: No module named os
dpkg: error processing python-sip (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing libqt3-mt ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-qt3
 python-sip
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
tv@tv:/usr/lib$
```

Second from trying to import the os module in a regular python prompt in the terminal:

```
tv@tv:~$ python
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named os
>>>
```